# Can I make the name of a string change each time a loop repeats?

Tags: java

Basically I need a different string created each time a loop repeats. I need a new string each time the loop repeats so I can store a whole bunch of different names and recall them as needed.

Thanks for any help I can get, I know its a little vague sorry bout that.

Comment: Try making it less vague next time. This site can help: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use the java [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) framework:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
while(someCondition()) {
    // Call add() as much as you like - the List will grow as needed
    strings.add("some new string"); // create whatever String you like
}
```

Now variable `strings` contains a bunch of String objects.

Later, you can iterate over the strings to do something with them:

```
for(String string : strings) {
    System.out.println(string); // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array or a list outside the loop and add a new string every time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to store your strings in a Map, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an array.

An array is like a list of variables. So you can make a new array called mystring, and then mystring[0], mystring[1], mystring[2] are all different variables. In your loop you can use your index value i to do mystring[i] and get a new variable for each time the loop repeats.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: arrays don't automatically grow - use a List